# Is it possible to fetch either which signers haven't signed a document OR which signers have signed what documents?

Tags: docusignapi

This is in the context of figuring out which signers to chase to sign docs.

I am using C# with DocuSign NuGet package installed.

So far I've tried:

- EnvelopeAPI.ListAuditEvents(...)
- EnvelopeAPI.ListRecipients(...)

using a test of single signer + multiple docs and multi-signer single doc.

I found that the above methods only show action/status of completed when the doc was signed by all signers and/or when the signer had signed all docs attached to the envelope. It didn't appear to provide a status for recipient like part-signed with another property listing what docs recipient has signed.

I also had a look at EnvelopeAPI.ListDocuments(...) - All examples I found don't use the ListDocumentsOption param and I couldn't seem to figure out how this is used like passing "true" for ShowFileSize did nothing. Also the results return a list of documents but with no property / info on it's status as signed and by whom.

I'm wondering if DocuSign API supports this level of detail.

Comment: I've just looked into setting up DocuSign Connect WebHook using the Webhook.site website to see what data is in the payloads and not finding any difference to what I've already found with the ListAuditData(...) method.

Comment: I had "Recipient Signed / Completed" but as the text suggests the this webhook event is only fired after I sign ALL the docs, instead of able to feedback Doc1 signed by Signer1.

Comment: When I tried including document data it just tells me info I can already get i.e. name of file, size, pdf - just enough to identify what doc was sent with what envelope id.

Comment: When I tried including tabs data, again it just list these tabs were added to the envelope.

Comment: In conclusion, I looking highly likely that DocuSign isn't able to report back when doc1 of 2 is signed only when both docs require signer1 to sign both docs.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that maybe influencing my findings is that the docs are shown "inline" i.e. like one pdf file. I wonder if this property has to change to get the webhook to feedback per doc, which would solve single signer multi-doc problem.

Comment: However, the multi-signer + multi-doc problem will still remain although, the webhook may fire per recipient . . . I would have to try this test case and what the webhook does.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using [DocuSign Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/), which is a webhook that sends events to your app. You can subscribe to per-recipient event that will tell you each time a recipient has signed.

If you have 5 recipients, you'll know each time a recipient signed, and you have the original list of recipients (which you can also get again) so those who didn't inform you they signed - did not sign yet.

You do this by picking this option from the list of events in the Connect Configuration (under Settings in your account)
[image]